# Can Grails 3 apps created with profile=web-api have gsps?

Tags: grails, gsp

I'm attempting to make a single page app using the web-api profile in Grails 3.

The only view Grails will load is the index page for the SPA. This can be either an index.html file or preferably an index.gsp.

My URLMappings looks like this: `"/"(controller: '/index')`

And I have a index.gsp in `/grails-app/views/index.gsp`

When I access localhost:8080/ I get a 404 back.

Any ideas? I've tried a few ways now and feel like it's something obvious that I'm just overlooking.

Thanks in advance

Comment: You will have to add back the `grails-gsp` gradle plugin in `build.gradle`. Create a sample app using the default profile and grab that gradle plugin dependency from its build file to your app. Eventually there will be no difference with a web profile and web-api (rest-api) profile. You can better use web profile if you need gsps. :)

Comment: tried adding the grails-gsp but same error kept showing up. Just going to take your advice and use the web profile :)

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you have a controller as below:

```
class MyController{
  def index(){
     render "hello world!!"
  }
}
```

you must write url mapping as below:

> "/"(controller:'my',action:'index')

Comment: When I try that, I get a 500 error: `ERROR org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/].[grailsDispatcherServlet] - Servlet.service() for servlet [grailsDispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Could not resolve view with name '/index/index' in servlet with name 'grailsDispatcherServlet'] with root cause
javax.servlet.ServletException: Could not resolve view with name '/index/index' in servlet with name 'grailsDispatcherServlet'`

Comment: URL Mapping: `"/"(controller: 'index', action: 'index')`

Controller:
`
package example

class IndexController {

    def index() {

    }

}`

View: `/grails-app/views/index/index.gsp`

Answer (score 0):

No, they don't.

As you can read on the docs

```
grails create-app my-api --profile rest-api
```

Will create an application that has

*Few plugins than the default Grails plugin (no GSP, no Asset Pipeline, Nothing HTML related)*

Please, note: wep-api is now rest-api

http://docs.grails.org/latest/guide/webServices.html#restProfile